# How to structure Firestore database to store user favorites and allow the app to know if a post is a favorite

Tags: firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore, serverless

Hello I am trying to build somewhat of a social media application which users can like posts. I want to be able to save the posts (which i guess is to store the reference of the post in the user's favorites). My problem however is, with that method, how do I enable the user to know he has already favorited a post he opens?

Answer (score 0):

To reduce read operations I would recommend to store the likes into a separated collection `likes` with a structure like this:

```
likes-postID-userID-(value true)
```

To check if a user liked a post you can read then just that single value and if you listen to it in realtime you can make your UI depending on the database value itself and don't need to check your app state for that. Every like button could then be a separated component/module/widget (dependning what you use) that needs just the userID and postID to know what to show and how to change the data on press.